# Magento 2 : Create and Handle Many to Many Relationship Between Two Table

Tags: magento2, custom, table

I have two custom table that is related by many to many relationships. So how to create these two tables: is there a specific syntax? and how to handle this type of relation thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at the table "catalog_category_product". you always need a 3rd table when doing n:m relations between tables

Comment: thanks for your replay brother